# SwiftUI .background modifier isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a reason as to why the .background modifier on SwiftUI is not changing colors?

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXj4E.png)

I tried restarting Xcode and even creating a new project and I'm still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Rectangle()` has `Color.black` opaque foreground color, so any background will be invisible below it.

You can use instead

```
Rectangle().fill(Color.white)
```

or

```
Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

The background (around the rectangle) is white, try use .fill() instead